# error Could not find an overload for '%' that accepts the supplied arguments

Tags: ios, swift, ios8

labelGen.text = [self, arc4random() % 1000]

give's me error => "Could not find an overload for '%' that accepts the supplied arguments"

Help me please

Comment: Not exactly an answer, but you should use arc4random_uniform rather than arc4random with a modulo - https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/Manpages/man3/arc4random_uniform.3.html

Comment: Yeah, don't use %, otherwise you'll get modulo bias anyway. For Swift, see [this existing question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24058195/what-is-the-easiest-way-to-generate-random-integers-within-a-range-in-swift)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Though its not clear what you want to achieve, I think you want a random number as a string. You can get it as below.

```
NSUInteger random = arc4random()%1000;
labelGen.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",random];
```

In you code,

```
labelGen.text = [self, arc4random() % 1000]
```

the `arc4random()` function is c function not Objective-C function, show you can not call it on self. Also this expression will give you `unsigned int` value not a `NSString` value.